# Python Redis Stream wait until message recieved

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

currently working on a project involving Python Flask and Redis. I would like to use Redis streams to get user input and send them to a backend microservice for processing. Then the results would be returned via stream back to the flask application to be displayed.

It seems like there are three redis compatible modules for Python. `Redis-Py`, `ReJSON`, and `Walrus`. Of the three `Walrus` has the best documentation but no JSON support and `ReJSON` has support for JSON but no Streams support.

Currently the Redis database is running in docker with the RedisJSON module enabled.

flaskapp.py

```
from walrus import *
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

db = Walrus(host=`redis-api`, port=6379, password='testpassword', db=0)

stream = db.Stream('stream-one')


class siteAPI_GP(Resource):

    # Returns existing Queries
    def get(self):
        queries = db.get('queryDB').decode('utf-8')

        return {'message': 'Success', 'data': queries}, 200

    # Adds new Query
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('identifier', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('query', required=True)

        args = parser.parse_args()

        # Here I would like to add the variable args to stream-one
        msgid1 = stream.add({'message': args})

        return {'message': 'Query Recieved', 'data': args}, 201    

# Create routes
api.add_resource(siteAPI_GP, "/query")
```

backend.py

```
   from walrus import *

redis_host = "redis-api"
redis_port = 6379
redis_password = "Password:)"

# Connet to DB
db = Walrus(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, password=redis_password, db=0)

# Connect to Stream
stream = db.Stream('stream-one')
```

Here is some pseudocode for what i would like to happen in `backend.py` after the script connect to the stream. Whats the best way of doing this?

```
    for message-received in stream-one:
    execute some code
else 
    print "still waiting for message"
```

I am currently thinking of using the `Walrus` modules in all Python scripts except `flaskapp.py` where I will use both `ReJSON` and `Walrus` to provide both streams and json functionality.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps kombu might do what you need? https://github.com/celery/kombu

Comment: @IainShelvington  I had a look at RabbitMQ and Celery but Redis seems like a nice lightweight alternative for a small project

Comment: kombu has built-in support for redis

Comment: @IainShelvington Will take a look. Thanks!